# Problema ao compilar python nas bibliotecas pyqt, com py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt

Estou tentando compilar com `py2exe`, mas quando vou compilar da erro.

Vou dar um exemplo que da esse erro, com os programas Python 2.7 64 bits, pyqt4 para Python 2.7, e `py2exe` para Python 2.7.

#### Segue o exemplo:

Crie um arquivo `teste.py` com corpo:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
```

Crie um arquivo `setup.py` com o corpo:

```
from distutils.core import setup  
import py2exe
setup(console=['teste.py'])
```

Depois compile:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

E ocorre o erro:

```
error: compiling
'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\port_v3\proxy_base.py' failed
SyntaxError: invalid syntax <proxy_base.py, line 26>
```

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a informação deste site:
[PyQt 4.7 and py2exe error](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/PyQt-4-7-and-py2exe-error-td1922933.html)

Há uma recomendação para remover (ou mover temporariamente para algum outro local), o diretório `port_v3`, que na sua pergunta está no caminho:

`C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\port_v3`

Neste outro site:
[PyQt4 compiling issues](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-53822.html)

Há uma recomendação para, além de remover a pasta `port_v3`, usar o seguinte comando para gerar o executável:

`python "setup.py py2exe --includes sip"`

Uma sugestão: antes de você remover a pasta, você pode tentar o comando acima para gerar o executável e, se não funcionar, aí sim tentar remover a pasta e gerar novamente (com o comando completo, incluindo o `sip`).

Comment: Agora deu o seguinte erro:
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MSVCP90.dll'

Comment: Você tem o [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) instalado? Caso não tenha, você precisa instalar e colocar o diretório `bin` do VC no seu PATH (o caminho onde ele instala é algo como:  `C:\Users\seu_usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin` ou, executar no prompt, o comando `C:\Users\seu_usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat` (solução melhor) antes gerar o exe. Se der certo, me avise para eu atualizar a resposta

Comment: Instalei o programa que vc sugeriu, adicionei no path, executei o script, e mesmo assim continua reclamando o MSVCP90.dll

Comment: Descobri como resolver o problema, so remover a dll na hora de compilar assim:
setup(options = {"py2exe": { "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"]}}, console=['teste.py'])

Comment: Agora eu tentei compilar o codigo completo, a compilação completa, mas na hora de abrir o programa da o seguinte erro:
Import Error: No module named QtNetwork

Comment: Andei pesquisando um pouco e descobri mais opcoes, agora estou melhorando o codigo do compilador:
setup(options = {"py2exe": { "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"], "includes":["sip", "PyQt4", "PyQt4.QtNetwork", "PyQt4.QtWebKit"]}}, console=['programa.py'])
Porem ele ainda esta reclamando
No module named QtWebKit.QWebView

Comment: Tem uma resposta [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081528/error-on-trying-to-convert-a-python-file-into-an-executable-with-cx-freeze) no SO (em inglês) falando sobre esse erro. E uma outra [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922711/importerror-no-module-named-qtwebkit) dizendo para confirmar se o Qt está instalado com o Webkit e se existe a biblioteca do Qt no caminho `C:\python2.7\site-packages\PyQt4`. Talvez ajude!

Comment: Dentro da pasta C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\sip\PyQt4\QtWebKit existe um arquivo chamado qwebview.sip, mas nao sei como ajuda saber disso

Comment: @MegaAnim no post, o autor se refere à biblioteca para sistema Linux, com extensão `so`. No Windows, provavelmente, deve ser um arquivo `dll`.

Comment: mas voce viu o que eu disse? Com o python normal funciona o componente.. Quando faço
python programa.py o programa funciona, o componente qwebview abre normal.
O erro só da quando compilo o programa com o py2exe

Comment: No linux não existe algo como o py2exe, isso é so pra windows, então eu não vejo em que ajudaria algo que tem haver com linux, em um compilador que so tem pra windows

Comment: @MegaAnim Realmente, o `py2exe` é exclusivo para a plataforma Windows. Porém, para gerar um exe portável, o `py2exe` precisa colocar todas as dependências do programa (dlls, módulos, etc.) dentro do arquivo exe. O que, provavelmente está acontecendo é que o executável não está encontrando alguma biblioteca (ou módulo) necessária para a execução.

Comment: Isso eu ja tinha entendido, como pode ver meus comentarios acima eu inclui, o sip, o PyQt4, e o PyQt4.QtNetwork, e o PyQt4.QtWebKit...
Qual mais eu tenho que incluir, essa é minha duvida

Comment: @MegaAnim O problema que você apresentou na [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111407/problema-ao-compilar-python-nas-bibliotecas-pyqt-com-py2exe) original foi solucionado, certo? Por favor, se tiver dúvidas, faça uma nova pergunta sobre o  problema que apareceu depois, com detalhes e tudo o que você tentou

Comment: E aí conseguiu? Estou lendo os comentários e morreu o assunto...